# External SSD mounted drive has corrupted inode used count

Tags: filesystems, mount, raspberry-pi, ssd, inode

I have two internal SSDs (one 120GB, other 128GB), each plugged to one of [these Sabrent external SSD enclosure](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00OJ3UJ2S). One of them started failing right away so I gave up on it thinking it could just be a faulty SSD that wasn't used for a few years and I didn't store it very carefully.

But now the second one is failing too, in a very weird way, so I'm starting to think the enclosures are having a part in this. I have a single and new `ext4` partition that I'm mounting on a RaspberryPi "server" running the RaspberryPi version of Debian 10 (RaspberryPi OS).

This happened a few times now already: the drive works fine for a while, then it suddenly vanishes, usually during a bigger write operation like `cp`ing some files. Running `lsblk -l` or `fdisk -l` doesn't detect it anymore until I reboot the system, and the respective `/dev` entries are also gone.

Tried running `fsck` on it but it always starts spewing out an infinite stream of random numbers after the fourth or fifth step, and then I have to close the ssh window and reconnect to be able to access the server again.

After a few cycles of this issue, now it's not working anymore for writes. I can still mount and read from it, but I noticed that, despite having a small-ish number of files (I counted, it was around 30k), it seems that the drive has a 100% utilization of `inodes`, which just looks plain wrong.

This is what happens after a fresh reboot and mount, if I try to write something to it (it's mounted to `/mnt/data`):

```
rodpi@rodpi-02:/mnt/data $ df -i
Filesystem                Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root                3890592 74148   3816444    2% /
devtmpfs                  452578   440    452138    1% /dev
tmpfs                     485802     1    485801    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     485802   695    485107    1% /run
tmpfs                     485802     3    485799    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                     485802    15    485787    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1                 0     0         0     - /boot
tmpfs                     485802    10    485792    1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sda1                7700480    11   7700469    1% /mnt/data

rodpi@rodpi-02:/mnt/data $ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': No space left on device

rodpi@rodpi-02:/mnt/data $ df -i
Filesystem                Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root                3890592   74148   3816444    2% /
devtmpfs                  452578     440    452138    1% /dev
tmpfs                     485802       1    485801    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     485802     695    485107    1% /run
tmpfs                     485802       3    485799    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                     485802      15    485787    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1                 0       0         0     - /boot
tmpfs                     485802      10    485792    1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sda1                7700480 7700480         0  100% /mnt/data
```

Two things wrong there: `inodes` is wrong before (11 is way too low for the number of files present), and is also wrong after, as it instantly jumps to 100%.

Also adding the output of `fdisk -l` when it works:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 117.4 GiB, 126035288064 bytes, 246162672 sectors
Disk model:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc97a5729

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 246162671 246160624 117.4G 83 Linux
```

---

Now, given that the first drive was showing the same symptoms (vanishing out of nowhere / fsck not completing), but I stopped using that straight away, could this be caused by the enclosure? The drives are from different manufacturers, and one is +/- 4 years old, while the other may be 5 or 6 years old, but again, I haven't used them in at least 3 years, so they're technically relatively new in terms of usage.

And another question, does this look fixable? If I were to use a different enclosure and re-create the partitions, could they work fine again?

Comment: Read `man mke2fs`. When you are re-creating the filesystem, you can specify the number of inodes with `-N`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't help. `inodes` being full cannot be from regular usage, it appears to be corrupted, as I explained in my question, so just increasing it won't fix any of the current issues.